# Remove List<String> duplicates using equals

Tags: java, list, duplicates, equals

I'm fairly new to Java and I've been trying to solve the following problem unsuccessfully.

Write a Java method that will remove duplicates from a given list.

Assuming:

1. Method accepts type List
2. Return type is `void`
3. Duplicates are determined using `equals()`

Main:

1. Creates an instant of List and loads it with duplicate String values
2. Invoke `removeDuplicates()`, pass in this list
3. Outputs modified list to the console.

I can solve the problem by passing in my list to a new HashSet and copy it back. 
But the problem is:

1. Question is asking me to solve it using `equals()...`
2. If the return type is `void`, how can i output it in the `main` ?

import java.util.*;
    public class Question1 {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
String[] words = {"good","better", "best", "best", "first" , "last", "last", "last", "good"};  
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();  
        for (String s : words) {  
            list.add(s);  
        }  
        removeDuplicates(list);
    }
    static void removeDuplicates(List<String> array){
        HashSet<String> hs = new HashSet<>();
        hs.addAll(array);
        array.clear();
        array.addAll(hs);
        for (String x : array){ 
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: well, this one works, but as you can see i'm not using equals() and i'm printing out from my static method, not from main. 
Also, is there any way I can populate the List faster than using String[] ?

Comment: put up your code, working or not.

Comment: Wanted: Code. Dead or alive.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Award must be a Great answer :P

Comment: By the way, HashSet uses equals in the add operation under the hood, so you can just explain that to your teacher: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add(E)

Comment: Move the output-loop to the main method!

Comment: You can print the method parameter, because you pass the reference of object, so, every changes will be on the given parameter object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you would do the same thing without using a `Set` and just using `equals()` (also to somewhat answer your "EDIT" question about initializing a `List`) :

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[] {
        "good", "better", "best", "best", "first", "last", "last", "last",
        "good"}));
    removeDuplicates(list);
    for (String x : list) {
      System.out.println(x);
    }
  }

  static void removeDuplicates(List<String> array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
      String next = array.get(i);

      // check if this has already appeared before
      for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        // if it has, stop the search and remove it
        if (next.equals(array.get(j))) {
          array.remove(i);
          // decrement i since we just removed the i'th element
          i--;
          // stop the search
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

That said, using `HashSet` is a better idea since as has already been pointed out it is more efficient.

If you want the efficiency of `HashSet` but still preserve the order of the `List` you could do something like this :

```
  static void removeDuplicates(List<String> array) {
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
      String next = array.get(i);

      // check if this has already appeared before
      if (!set.add(next)) {
        // if it has then remove it
        array.remove(i);
        // decrement i since we just removed the i'th element
        i--;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why not use an `LinkedHashSet` instead to preserve order??

Answer (score 3):

`java.util.HashSet` uses `Object.equals(Object)` in its implementation of `Set.add(Object)` to determine that the element being inserted is unique (as defined by not being equal to another element). HashSet also has the advantage of allowing you to do the de-duping process in `O(n)` time vs a more naive approach of comparing every element to every other element in `O(n^2)` time.

The code in `main` will see the modified list, because the List object is mutable. When a  method changes the state of a passed in argument the calling code will see those changes.

Answer (score 2):

1. `removeDuplicates` creates a [set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Set.html), then iterates over the input list. If it encounters an element in the input list, that is also in the set, `removeDuplicates` removes the element from the input list, otherwise it adds the element to the set.
2. Java is a call-by-reference language ([sort of](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm)). This means, the method `removeDuplicates` can modify the `List<String> array` that it receives and the caller will see that modified list after the call to `removeDuplicates` returned.

Answer (score 1):

The probably easiest way would be to use a Set in the first place, which by definition does not allow duplicates.

For your actual problem, you can do several approaches:

- The easy but slow approach: compare each element A with each other element N in the list. If A.equals(N) remove N. Hint: you only need to compare A to each further element, as you have already checked each element before A.
- The faster approach: sort the list using the natural comperator. Now you no longer need to compare each element A vs N, but only A vs the next few elements. To be exact: until you find the first element that is not equal to A. In this case you can assume that there is no further duplicate of A (thanks to the sorting) and continue with this next element as A.
- The Map approach (fast but takes more memory): for each element put into the list, put the same element into a Map with any Object as value. Now you can just look-up whether or not that element is already in the map, and if it is, it is a duplicate.

The best way would be the 2nd approach as the sorting is very fast, you only need to get each element once, and there is no 2nd list necessary.

Edit: The 2nd approach in code:

```
static void removeDuplicates(List<String> array) {
  if (array.size() <= 1) {
    return;
  }
  Collections.sort(array);
  final Iterator<String> it = array.iterator();
  String a = it.next(), n;
  while (it.hasNext()) {
    n = it.next();
    if (((a == null) && (n != null))
            || ((a != null) && (a.equals(n) == false))) {
      a = n;
    } else {
      it.remove();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("good");
        list.add("better");
        list.add("best");
        list.add("best");
        list.add("first");
        list.add("last");
        list.add("last");
        list.add("last");
        list.add("good");
        removeDuplicates(list);
        System.out.println(list.toString());
    }

    public static void removeDuplicates(List<String> list) {
        if (list != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                ListIterator<String> listIterator = list.listIterator();

                while (listIterator.hasNext()) {
                    int nextIndex = listIterator.nextIndex();
                    String nextElement = listIterator.next();
                    if (list.get(i).equals(nextElement) && i != nextIndex)
                        listIterator.remove();

                }

            }
        }

    }

}
```